# Change response submitted from rest controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I tried using filters and Interceptors to modify the response submitted from the controller method but i was unable to do as the response is committed before executing the filter or interceptor.
I knew we have another option with ResponseBodyAdvice but thats not the correct place for me to do, because the intention is to modify the response based on the HTTP status. If any one have idea please let me know, how can i achieve with spring boot and Rest

Comment: "modify the response based on the HTTP status". How are you getting this status? Please post one of the controller method. Also describe what do you want to do in the response from that controller method.

Comment: @RamanujanR I can response status from the response object inside Filter and Interceptor , but not in ResponseBodyAdvice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it. Just Create a class say XYZ which you have to make an interceptor, and then make that class extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` class. As far as i remember, this class has four methods which you can override, which are as follows:

```
preHandle(...)
postHandle(...)
afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(...)
afterCompletion(...)
```

So, according to your need, you can use the last method namely: `afterCompletion(...)` method, because, this method gets executed, when we are ready to render the view to the client.
Then you have to register that class XYZ as bean inside `<mvc:interceptor>` tag if you are using the xml pattern.

Comment: As i mentioned, before executing the aftercompletion the response is committed . So once response is committed we can't do anything

Comment: then use the postHandle() method... to make final changes to the view.. @user3004406